# How to prevent UIPopoverPresentationController from being dismissed when clicking outside popover?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

In my universal iOS 8 app, I am presenting a popover using using `UIPopoverPresentationController` as seen below from `prepareForSegue`:

```
FavoriteNameViewController *nameVC = segue.destinationViewController;
UIPopoverPresentationController *popPC = nameVC.popoverPresentationController;
popPC.delegate = self;
```

And with this delegate method.

```
- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller {
return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```

In this particular case, I'm presenting a view controller that looks like an alert, but isn't.

[image]

Now my issue is that the user can click outside of this popover and it gets dismissed.  There's no real problem with that except that's not how alerts work and I would like this to emulate an alert.

I see that `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` had a method called `popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:`, but `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` doesn't have that method, and I believe I need to use the latter.

Comment: Could we talk now (what you sort of refused to do in your earlier question) about why you're not using a presented view for this? Why don't you just do what I do here: make a presented view that looks like and behaves like an alert view? https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7 - This would also solve the problem of the popover that isn't a popover in landscape on iPhone 6 plus.

Comment: The reason I went the route I did is because when I searched for how to present a popover that was the method I found.  I will check out your project for a better understanding of what you're talking about.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to set the popover controller's `passthroughViews` to `nil` and the view controller's `modalInPopover` to YES.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following in your view

```
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    return YES;
}
```